How do I get the URL property from a locator in playwright?
I am running Playwright in .NET against a page full of links. I have collected the links with the following:
var collectionOfLinks = await Page.GetByRole(Microsoft.Playwright.AriaRole.Link).AllAsync();
var countOfLinks = collectionOfLinks.Count();
for (var i = 0; i < countOfLinks; i++)
{
  var link = collectionOfLinks[i];
// do some work with the links
}

I have tried variations of
var linkUrl = link.getAttribute("href");
and
var linkUrl = link.getHref();
Nothing I've tried builds.

Did you try GetAttributeAsync? When something doesn't build, which error tells you that?

I tried GetAttributeAsync but it returns a Task and what I need is the string.

Please try awaiting it.
